# Python Circle - Pixel by pixel

Tags: python, graphics, python-imaging-library

So, I saw a related 'topic' question on here, but it is using a different method.

Further, I understand there are more efficient algorithms out there such as Mid-point/Bresenham's.

Yet, at least thus far in my discovery, perhaps 'simple and traditional' is best for my needed end-point application.

Thus I put together this tiny Python app to experiment. I needed to at least ensure that descending radii of a circle described this way would cover the area. Again, I fully understand there would be much easier ways to make a circle, and a fill--

But that is not really what I'm after. I just need to determine a list of all the (x,y) pixel points, in the end, that describe it.

However, at first, this is of course much easier to see 'visually'.

So, from my simple code:

```
from PIL import Image
import math
import numpy as np

img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 800), color = (255, 255, 255))

x = 400
y = 400
#r = 300

for r in range(0, 300, 1):
    for i in np.arange(0, 361, 0.1):
        angle = i
        x1 = math.trunc(r * math.cos(angle * math.pi / 180))
        y1 = math.trunc(r * math.sin(angle * math.pi / 180))
        #print ("(" + str(x + x1) + "," + str(y + y1) + ")")
        img.putpixel((x + x1, y + y1), (0, 0, 0, 255))
img.show()
```

I guess I am a little confused as to how/why I am blanking out in these four points, one in each quadrant, almost exactly like a square:

[image]

Anyone have a guess 'what gives ?'

Comment: They probably go away when you don't restrict yourself to integer `r`.

Comment: Drawing circles in polar coordinates is criminal, due to the high cost of evaluating the trigonometric functions and the fact that you fill the same points several times. The white dots appear because some large circles are not perfectly adjoining. This will worsen with larger radii.

Comment: But are you after drawing circles or filling disks ?

Comment: I know this may sound a bit 'convoluted', but there is a very specific reason I'm doing it 'somewhat' like this. I want to raster an image, but have it come out in the shape of a circle. So, I guess somewhat of an analogy is if you were to imaging a line beam on an old radar screen. I want that to 'populate' the image but I need to know what x,y points to pull the original pixels from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate over the pixels themselves and not over polar coordinates in arbitrary steps:

```py
r_squared = r*r
for x1 in range(0, r):
  for y1 in range(0, r):
    if x1*x1 + y1*y1 < r_squared:
      img.putpixel((x + x1, y + y1), (0, 0, 0, 255))
      img.putpixel((x + x1, y - y1), (0, 0, 0, 255))
      img.putpixel((x - x1, y + y1), (0, 0, 0, 255))
      img.putpixel((x - x1, y - y1), (0, 0, 0, 255))
```

Comment: Drawing just the outline is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

As you also asked *why* you missed these pixels, I've created an image resolving them, i.e. showing the discrete pixels obtained from your transformation:

```py
        x1 = math.trunc(r * math.cos(angle * math.pi / 180))
        y1 = math.trunc(r * math.sin(angle * math.pi / 180))
```

as alternating colors in `r`–`angle` space.

I find it illustrative to see how how/which pixels are covered by your raster (×):

```py
for r in range(0, 300, 1):
    for angle in np.arange(0, 361, 0.1):
```

I think this shows nicely how some (color-coded in green) are just very briefly missed:

[image: Rendering a filled circle in polar coordinates with Δr=1, Δφ=0.1° misses some pixels]

Comment: Dear Manfred, this is great. I am still not 'exactly' sure yet this is the algorithm I need, but I was curious how yours worked, as it does produce a full and consistent circle. So I popped into Pygame, gave it some random colors based on the x1, y1 values, and then recorded this video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/wze1zGYwBEc I don't know if it will let me post the code here... I am kind of new to Stack. But the one other thing I added is I reordered (and commented) on your transforms so now it is clear which is quadrant I, II, II, IV.

Comment: #Quadrant I:
      circle_surface.set_at((x + x1, y - y1), (0, y1, 0))

      #Quadrant II:
      circle_surface.set_at((x - x1, y - y1), (0, x1, y1))

      #Quadrant III:
      circle_surface.set_at((x - x1, y + y1), (0, 0, x1))

      
      #Quadrant IV:
      circle_surface.set_at((x + x1, y + y1), (x1, 0, 0))


      pygame.display.flip()